# How can I get the most current frame in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to take and display the most current frame on any key event. It is important for me that the photo will be taken only once (without using infinity loop). I have a problem because displayed photo is the previous one not the most current. It looks like some buffor with captured frames in VideoCapture object.

I'm using OpenCV 4.6.0 and laptop camera.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap0(0);

    cv::Mat frame0;
    for (;;)
    {
        cap0.read(frame0);
        if (!frame0.empty())
        {
            imshow("cap0", frame0);
        }
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to get and display current photo without doing infinity loop whenever I click any key?

Comment: Capture (read) in another thread and drop all frames, only keep the latest one. Display the latest one after keypress.

Comment: Try placing `cv::waitKey(0);` before `cap0.read(frame0); instead of after`: `if (!frame0.empty()) cv::waitKey(0);`. The issue is, that you are not going to see the video. If you want to watch the video, and pause when key is pressed, replace `cv::waitKey(0);` with: `int key = cv::waitKey(1);if (key > 0) cv::waitKey(0);`

Comment: @Micka I thought about this solution but is it possible to do it without multithreading? I mean I want to capture (and display) image only when I want to do it (not in infinity loop even if it is in other thread).

Comment: @Rotem Unfortunately it's not working. Still previous photo is displayed. And I want to capture image only on keypress (without video and pausing).

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-can-i-get-the-most-current-frame-in-opencv/10635